# Wrapper generator SWIG (C++/Perl): How to access "blessed" objects in a 1d vector<double>in Perl?

Tags: c++, perl, vector, double, swig

I have written a C++ library to extract simulation data (= simple vectors with (x,y) or (x,y,z) components) from electronic design automation (EDA) tools. More concrete, this data represents electrical signals for different points in time.

The C++ library offers several methods. Two important ones are:

```
std::vector<std::string> getSignalNames() // Returns all signal names in the file
std::vector<std::vector<double>> getSignals() // Returns the actual data as M x N matrix (with M rows and N columns)
```

Using the library in C++ works perfectly and yields the expected results, e.g.:

```
getSignalNames():
  Signal1
  Signal2
getSignals():
  1 1 1 2
  2 1 2 3
```

Perl programmers asked me to also offer the library to them and I decided to use [the wrapper generator SWIG](http://www.swig.org/index.php) to create bindings. I worked through [the tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) and I was able to successfully set up a minimal working example.

Based on the example, I wrote a complete SWIG interface file for the C++ library. The wrapper generation and build process works smoothly and I can also use `getSignalNames()` without any problems:

```
// Perl snippet to read out signal names
my $parserPointer = new waveformparser::ScopeParser("input.file");
$signalNames = $parserPointer->getSignalNames();

foreach my $signalName ( @$signalNames ) {
    print "$signalName\n";
}
// Output:
Signal1
Signal2
```

But, I ran into trouble when using the return value from `getSignals()`:

```
// Perl snippet to read out the actual signal data
my $parserPointer = new waveformparser::ScopeParser("input.file");
$signalData = $parserPointer->getSignals();

foreach my $rowAsHashRef ( @$signalData ) {
    print "reftype: " . reftype($rowAsHashRef) . "\n";
    print "keys: " . keys(%$rowAsHashRef) . "\n"
}
// Output:
reftype: HASH
keys: 0
reftype: HASH
keys: 0
```

As you see, each row is represented as hash in Perl, but there are no keys in the Hash. Nevertheless, when using [Perl's Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper), I can see the correct data type for each row:

```
my $parserPointer = new waveformparser::ScopeParser("input.file");
$signalData = $parserPointer->getSignals();
print Dumper $signalData;
// Output:
$VAR1 = [
          bless( {}, 'waveformparser::vector_1d_double' ),
          bless( {}, 'waveformparser::vector_1d_double' )
];
```

I.e., according to the data dumper, each row consists of several columns (i.e., `'waveformparser::vector_1d_double'`) which are defined in the SWIG interface file as following:

```
...
%include "std_vector.i"
%template(vector_1d_double) std::vector<double>;
%template(vector_2d_double) std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
...
```

**My question is now: How can I access elements of this "blessed" (wrapped) `vector_1d_double` objects in Perl?**

I thought, SWIG would provide convenient access methods for such objects. I.e., the underlying C++ data type is just a simple 1d vector of doubles (`std::vector<double>`).

Comment: You probably need to write a typemap for `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, similar to what was done for `std::map<...>` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676394/how-to-convert-multidimensional-map-from-c-into-hash-in-perl)

Comment: You shouldn't have to write a typemap with the `std_vector.i` included.  You should include a [mcve] to see if there is anything wrong in your .i file.  The templates must be instantiated before processing the code headers via `%include`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an output typemap for `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` to convert to a proper Perl array of arrays. Here is an example:

**VecVec.i**:

```
%module VecVec
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<double>> {
    AV *array = (AV *) newAV();
    auto vec_ptr = &$1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>& vec = *vec_ptr;
    for (const auto &item : vec) {
        AV *subarray = (AV *) newAV();
        for (const auto &subitem : item) {
            av_push(subarray, newSVnv((NV) subitem));
        }
        av_push(array, (SV*) newRV_noinc((SV*)subarray));
    }
    $result = newRV_noinc((SV*) array);
    sv_2mortal($result);
    argvi++;
}
%{
    #include "VecVec.h"

%}
%include "VecVec.h"
```

**VecVec.h**:

```
#ifndef VEVEC_H_
#define VECVEC_H_
#include <vector>

class VecVec
{
public:
    VecVec() {}
    ~VecVec() {}
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> getSignals();
private:
};
#endif
```

**VecVec.cpp**:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "VecVec.h"

std::vector<std::vector<double>> VecVec::getSignals()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6}
    };
    return vec;
}
```

Then compile with:

```
perl_include_dir=$(perl -MConfig -e'print $Config{archlib}')"/CORE"
swig -perl5 -c++ -I/usr/include VecVec.i
g++ -fPIC -c VecVec.cpp
g++ -I${perl_include_dir} -c -fPIC -g -o VecVec_wrap.o VecVec_wrap.cxx
g++ -shared -L. VecVec.o VecVec_wrap.o -o VecVec.so
```

and test the module with **test.pl**:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use lib '.';
use VecVec;

my $p = VecVec::VecVec->new();
my $sig = $p->getSignals();
print Dumper($sig);
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3'
          ],
          [
            '4',
            '5',
            '6'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for the clear explanation and the working code - perfect. You made my day! :) The `%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<double>> {...}` definition was the missing puzzle in the SWIG interface file (*.i). I thought SWIG would generate this out of the box when using SWIG's `%template(...)` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> I thought, SWIG would provide convenient access methods for such objects. I.e., the underlying C++ data type is just a simple 1d vector of doubles (std::vector).

It should.  You do need to instantiate the templates before SWIG processes the functions, but you'll need to show a minimal, reproducible example to know for sure why it isn't working.

I'm not currently familiar with building a Perl extension, but here's a non-language-specific SWIG .i file that should work for Perl.  I'll demonstrate with Python:

test.i

```cpp
%module test

// Define templates before SWIG processes the code.
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%template(vector_string) std::vector<std::string>;
%template(vector_1d_double) std::vector<double>;
%template(vector_2d_double) std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

%inline %{
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> getSignalNames() {
    return {"abc","123"};
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> getSignals() {
    return {{1.1,2.2},{3.3,4.4}};
}
%}
```

The above includes everything in a standalone file.  I used `swig -c++ -python test.i` and compiled the resulting `test_wrap.cxx` file as a Python extension.

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.getSignalNames()
('abc', '123')
>>> test.getSignals()
((1.1, 2.2), (3.3, 4.4))
```

If SWIG's Perl support is comparable this .i file should work for you without defining your own output typemaps.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately, also your minimal working example does not yield the expected output when creating the Perl bindings and using them like this: `print Dumper(test::getSignals()); # Output: $VAR1 = [ bless( {}, 'test::vector_1d_double' ), bless( {}, 'test::vector_1d_double' ) ];` I don't know why, but when generating Perl bindings, SWIG requires an extra typemap to create proper bindings for a C++ `vector<vector<double>>` as pointed out by Håkon Hægland

Comment: See also this open ticket: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/566